# How to create a graph in Excel with cumulative changes without an accumulative sum chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, accounting

For three companies, I have an Excel export file from SAP which contains all bank transactions that occurred during 2021. Company A has 3 bank accounts, Company B has 2 and Company C has 1, so that's 6 bank accounts in total.

The data from Company A would look like this:

[image]

As can be seen, there are days on which no transactions occurred, so no lines with data are included. Now, I would like to create two graphs:

1. One which shows the ending balance per day per bank account on Y and time on X (so this graph has 6 lines in total);
2. One which shows the ending balance per day of all bank accounts combined on Y and time on X (if easier, this line can be include in graph 1).

I've read that the easiest way to create a cumulative graph is to include an extra column with cumulative data, which then will show the sum of incoming/outgoing transactions, which is the ending balance up to that date. But for me this is not preferable, as the dataset contains multiple companies and bank accounts, making it hard to calculate the cumulative value/ending balance per bank account.

So, to recap, is it possible to create a graph which shows the ending balance per bank account on a daily level, without adding an extra column to Excel to calculate the cumulative value?

Comment: based on your data you want to do a pivot chart, with some type of stacked line/bar

Comment: I agree with gns100, the Bacnk Account and Date field can be set as Rows and Series field.